# Compiling x64 DLL on x86

Tags: visual-c++, dll, x86, 64-bit

I am working on a wrapper DLL using the technique described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17863/Using-Pragmas-to-Create-a-Proxy-DLL

I was able to successfully build it on Windows Vista 32 bit using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2010. But I need to build the DLL for Vista x64 on my i386 machine.

Is it possible using MSVC express 2010?
Do I need a 64 bit copy of the DLL I intend to wrap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to say thanks for the unexplained downvotes. Very helpful for a newbie.

Anyway I fixed this myself by installing the Windows 7.1 SDK. That in itself took
significant effort. I had to uninstall the Visual C++ Runtime 2010 before it would
install for some reason.

Then I had another problem: linker errors about uuid.lib when I tried to the build the DLL

I had to tell the linker where to look with /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64"

That solved the problem

Comment: I know this was posted a while ago, SO can be tough, especially on newbies. I like the comic (maybe xkcd) where the guy posts a question, is told to google it, then finds the link to his own question on the top of the google search... an infinite loop. Thx for posting the solution.